# Skylake & Ubuntu 14.04 Dual Monitor

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel

I have a problem with setting up dual monitor on Ubuntu 14.04.
I'm using integrated graphics card Intel 530 to be precise,
And for some reason when connecting the HDMI port and Display Port together, the HDMI port doesn't work, but the when only the HDMI port is connected, the monitor works, try to find a solution and came back empty handed, if someone could help me)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my computers with dual screens, both using HDMI port and Display Port. It works for any combination of cable I'm using, be it HDMI, Display Port or even DVI-D and VGA.

I suggest you upgrade to at least Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It has new kernel that supports skylake graphic cards better.

Comment: Will try that out as soon as I get back to my PC

Answer (score 0):

[Bug #94248](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94248) for the Intel driver shows a similar problem when three monitors are used. They recommend updating the firmware of the LSPCon (the device that converts DP signal to HDMI). In case you have such a device (if your HDMI port supports HDMI 2.0, you have it), you should also try updating its firmware.